# Is there no way to connect an Ionic app to a localhost API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've tried everything there is to try. I've tried proxy, I've tried allowing CORS on my API. I think I've reached the extent of my Google searches. Is there really no way that I can test my app with a localhost API? I tried this, in my ionic.config.json I added this:

```
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8080"
    }
```

Then in my post request, I did this:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8100/api/users', payload).map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log("The result is");
  console.log(res);
}, error =>{
  console.log(error);
});
```

The url of the API is http://localhost:8080/users

I've tried this in a lot of ways and I have been unsuccessful. I am using `ionic serve` to run my app. Please, anyone that can help me out with this. I am really desperate at this point.

Comment: can you hit the API by other means? For example, through Postman?

Comment: Yes. Precisely by Postman it works

Comment: If you add an err => {console.log(err);} as a second parameter to the observable what do you get?

Comment: Edited question to show error parameter. It just keeps on giving status 500.

In the console I am getting this

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1194:14)`

Comment: Curiosly, when I try localhost:8080 on my postman, it works. But when I try 127.0.0.1:8080 it doesn't. I thought they were supposed to be the same?

Comment: Did you try the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)? I think that using the router asigned IP instead of 127.0.0.1 should work.

Comment: In your question you're using port 8100 on the post call. Should that be 8080?

Comment: I'm not using a device right now. I'm using the `ionic serve` command to run the app in my browser.

Comment: Also you have /api/users, is the endpoint /users?

Comment: @DavidX well I'm using 8100 because of the proxy. I thought that was how it worked.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot you we're using a proxy.

Comment: As @CarlKroegerIhl mentioned, I'd suggest swapping in your router assigned Ip.